# how to combine the 3 channels L*a*b*?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, color-space

I want to transform an  image in the lab space to the rgb space, but I can not use the lab2rgb command because I have three channels L*a*b*
so i have to merge the three channels first, how do I do it

Comment: you want to concatenate. `cat`

Comment: If you mean lab values are contained in three separate vectors, say `l`, `a`, `b` you can concatenate them in a new `lab = [l(:), a(:), b(:)]` variable to be called from `lab2rgb` (or directly write `rgb = lab2rgb([l(:), a(:), b(:)])`.